# didn't have or didn't had with if

Tags: tenses, sentence, adverbs

I need to know whether the sentence given below correct?

> Have something to eat, if you didn't have it earlier.

Comment: Consider: *Have something to eat, if you didn't have anything earlier.* or *Have the cake, if you didn't have it earlier.*

Answer (score 0):

You should replace "it" with "anything"

> Have something to eat, if you didn't have anything earlier.